# Obter imagem apenas de um setor em um scanner (python)

Tags: python, automatização, scanner

Boa tarde! Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação python e não estou conseguindo fazer com que o programa obtenha uma imagem de um setor do scanner, somente de toda a área que o scanner consegue varrer (aproximadamente uma folha A4). Ainda sou iniciante na linguagem.

Minha necessidade é monitorar uma área do scanner, realizando por exemplo 2 imagens por minuto. Só que eu não preciso de toda a folha A4 que o scanner é capaz. Preciso de um setor, um quadrado 10cm x 10cm.

Assim que o software detectar qualquer mudança da imagem anterior para a atual, gostaria que ele reproduzisse um som de alerta e parasse com o monitoramento.

Meu problema é que usando as lib **Twain 1.0.5** e **Image Scanner** eu não consigo definir uma área. Em todos os testes que realizei o obtido é sempre a "folha A4".

Estou aberto totalmente a sugestões, inclusive para troca de linguagem de programação. Meu receio (e palpite) é que estas bibliotecas supracitadas não deem conta do que eu preciso e eu não achei nenhuma outra para teste.

O mais próximo que cheguei do necessário foi quando modifiquei o valor no arquivo "simple_base.py" da biblioteca **Twain 1.0.5**:

> self.SD.RequestAcquire(0, 0)  # 1,1 to show scanner user interface

Ajustando o valor de (0, 0) para (1, 1) o programa abre uma janela do driver do scanner, onde eu consigo ajustar para que o scanner somente leia uma área. O problema é que isso é feito manualmente. Eu queria deixar uma área como padrão pois sempre é ela que deverá ser monitorada.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que tal recortar a imagem após o escaneamento? Seria aceitável para você? Recortar (crop) é simples usando Pillow.

Comment: @sergiopereira Infelizmente não é apropriado porque obter uma imagem em alta resolução através de um scanner, se for a folha toda, acaba levando mais do que 30 segundos e aí a precisão do monitoramento cai drasticamente. Já havia pensado na possibilidade, mas no teste não deu muito certo... Obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi: vc está usando um scanner pra fazer monitoramento de mudança em objeto qualquer (possivelmente um documento)? Eu *não acredito* que scanners sirvam bem pra esse tipo de tarefa. Principalmente porque como ele literalmente "escaneia" a imagem ao invés e capturá-la em uma tomada só, o desempenho pra esse tipo de tarefa é bem ruim mesmo. Além disso, documentos em um scanner não costumam mudar sozinhos (eles mudam quando o usuário os altera). Não seria melhor usar uma webcam, por exemplo? Talvez se você der mais detalhes do seu problema fique mais fácil uma sugestão.

Answer (score -2):

Pegue a folha A4 digitalizada pelo programa, veja a resolução em pixels dela (width, height), escolha a area que deseja utiliza e escreva algo assim usando, substitua os valores com as funções da lib que você usa (é só um palpite, não conheço a lib que você usa, mas tem grande chance de funcionar):

```
if ImageChange in ResoluçãoAreaQueDesejaUtilizar:
    script
```

ou tente usar os argumentos dos métodos da lib, ImageChange(ResoluçãoAreaQueDesejaUtilizar)

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão. Só não entendi como você está sugerindo, já que a resolução é igual para toda a folha e não vai ser de uma parte dela somente. A ideia não é cortar a imagem depois de scanear e sim já fazer scan da parte desejada

Comment: Cara, desculpe, eu interpretei mal a lib que você usa... mas você não consegue inserir uma area na função de scanear? por exemplo, 500x500 na pos 0, 0 ... também tem essa lib, parece boa, serve? http://python-sane.readthedocs.org/en/latest/